# Parse REST API date range query

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to figure out how I can make a request to the REST API for Parse that can accept a range against the createdAt column.  I can issue the following constraint which works but when I try a compound query that tries to do a GT and a LT constraint I get a Bad Request error.

`var requestParams = 'where={ "createdAt": { "$gt": { "__type": "Date", "iso": "' + startDate + '" } } } ';`

Is this possible with the REST API?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not quite sure in what format you are passing the `startDate`. The correct example to do such a thing is as follows.

```
curl
    -X GET
    -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: [APP_ID]"
    -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: [KEY]"
    -G --data-urlencode 'where={"createdAt":{"$gte":{ "__type": "Date", "iso": "2014-07-28T07:57:03.900Z" }}}'   
    https://api.parse.com/1/classes/[YOUR CLASS]
```

The example below shows how to do this using their Javascript SDK

[Javascript query using greaterThan "createdAt"](https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-query-using-greaterthan-createdat)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The date format is an ISO format and my where clause that I posted works.  What I am trying to do now is perform a $gt and $lt on createdAt.  By the looks of everything I have read, this is not possible with the REST API.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can query a date range by combining multiple conditions for the date column rather than listing the column multiple times, which is what I tried and what I assume you tried. This worked for me:

```
{
  "createdAt": {
    "$gte": {
      "__type": "Date",
      "iso": "2019-01-15"
    },
    "$lte": {
      "__type": "Date",
      "iso": "2019-07-15"
    }
  }
}
```